# Plotly producing a blank bar chart

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to produce a dashboard with plotly, wherein the graphs are sourced off a loaded dataframe. My problem currently is that upon creating a bar chart, the output is blank, even when I use a line chart, it works fine.

Here is a preview of my dataset:
It's a grouped-by object, I essentially have a larger dataset that I wanted topline figures for showing topline time series trends.

[preview of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT7hZ.jpg)

[data set types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ1x5.jpg)

```
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
data = [go.Bar(
        x=[Safe.Period],
        y=[Safe.Units]
)]

pl.offline.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

To which I get this blank output:

[blank output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Y06.jpg)

Now I've got it to work like this:

```
trace = go.Scatter(x= Topline.Period,
               y= Topline.Units,
                mode = "lines")
data = [trace]

pl.offline.iplot({"data":data})
```

[Line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga3ke.jpg)

So in a line chart, or at least a scatter connected by lines, the code works. but not when its done as a bar chart.

Can anybody shed some light on this/ recommend any fixes/checks? I'm still getting accustomed to plotly and hope to one day move my excel dashboarding into python/plotly.

Comment: Instead of pictures could you put some previews in here using markdown? This way we can copy them and put into python and test this ourselves.

Comment: I don't think I can. Everytime I enter the images as markdown I get an error saying I need a reputation of 10 to do so. Did you have something else in mind?